# would like to debug vb.net code to see methods run in base class

Tags: vb.net

I would like to be able to debug my code and actually step into the methods of the base class that are being run. I am running VB.net studio 2005. And when I currently use the debug step into, I will only see my code. But because my class is derived from the the system.windows.forms.form - I would like to see what methods from the this class are being run.

Hope someone can help . Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and it's Visual Studio add-in to do just that.